# How to make a deque of class objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, deque

I had a `deque` of structs (each containing an `int` id and a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>` timestamp): after a certain timeout, structs with elapsed timeout were removed from `deque`.

I thought of a different approach: instead of having a thread which loops over the `deque` to check the timeout of every single struct in it, I may put objects class in `deque`: when the constructor of this class is called and the object is going to be pushed in `deque`, a method is of this class is called; this method will make the object sleep for `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(/*#define TIMETOUT*/));` when the object resumes from sleep it sends a signal to a thread waiting on a `condition_variable'.

I read a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733424/queue-of-class-objects) (which made me discover wrapper classes) about queue of class objects, but I don't understand a few things: when I remove from `deque`, what is returned? A reference? The object itself? I need the object removed because I have to insert it into another `deque`.
And how do I properly create a class for my purpose, if wrapper is really needed?

Comment: Could you make your title more relevant to the actual question you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, any kind of sleep function wont help you: it freezes an entire thread, not an object. If you don't know what a thread is and how you use them, then your program is single-threaded and the entire program will freeze when you call sleep function.

Then, when you erase something from a deque, `deque::erase()` returns an iterator to a next object in the queue. This is useful when you iterate over a queue in a loop and you want to delete something.

If you want to copy an object somewhere, you need to do it first. After you delete it, there is no way to make a copy.

Finally, about wrapper classes: I have no idea why would you need to use them here. You can manually add an object to a different queue before you delete if from the first one.

Comment: Then, I should come back to my previous `struct` and start the controller thread. How do I know what is best between `struct` or an object class?
What is the reasoning that will make me choose `struct` instead of object class, or viceversa?

Comment: @elmazzun No, you probably don't need a separate thread. It would only make things more difficult. About a struct vs a class - choose whatever is more convenient to you.